# Google Chrome not showing accented characters

Tags: html

Why isn't this working? It's suppose to show the accented characters... but it seems it is not.

[image]

Edit: Switching it to `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />` will make the `c` in the first name the right one, but the two in the last name are still without accents...

Comment: I'm sorry? What do you mean.

Comment: Normally you can choose how to encode your file in the software you are using to develop.

Comment: It is a PHP file using HTML5 template...

Comment: You should check in your editor if the file is correctly encoded. Can you tell me which editor you're using?

Comment: I don't have this editor but you should check on top if you have something like Format/Encoding or something else and change the encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`.

Also, make sure the file encoding is something that can support those symbols as well (if your editor doesn't already just default to UTF-8).

Comment: Make sure the document itself is saved in UTF-8. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using phpDesigner... but how do I check that.. saves as UTF-8?

Comment: I've never used that developer, so I'm not positive. To check if it is the issue, you can download something like Notepad++ which is easy to set encoding. Then, if that is indeed the issue, you could ask another question for phpDesigner.

Answer (score 0):

Download the soft notepad++ and then open your file, click on encode and then on "convert to utf 8"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
However another Folder with the same setup worked:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

- so, create a new folder with another html.
- if it works, transfer names/content there.

Answer (score 0):

Even after changing file encoding type to UTF-8 the **Accented characters** are not shown properly , then follow these steps.

1: Open the file in the Notepad++.

2: Look at the bottom of Notepad++. If you see Windows(CR LF) then right click over it, change it to Unix(LF) and save the file.

This solved my error for Accented characters in chrome.